# LINQ: get into a loop by returning object with foreign key

Tags: c#, linq

I have created 2 tables `Apartment` and `Room` by drag-and-dropping them into the `LinqToSql.dbml` inside my project. The `Room` table contain a foreign key column, `apartment_id`. This column is created on `room` via `EntityRef<Apartment>` member, and to `Apartment` via `EntitySet<Room>` member

When I try to return all the rooms for a specific apartment id, it seems to get into a loop because it is trying to return the room members, and one of them is  `EntityRef<Apartment> _Apartment` and it is returning the apartment, but the apartment contains member `EntitySet<Room> _Rooms` and it is returning the room, and so on...

Query code :

```
[Route("api/Rooms/get_all_rooms_in_apartment")]
public List<Room> GetAllApartmentRooms(int i_apartmentId)
{
    List<Room> apartmentRooms =
        (from rooms in m_DataBase.Rooms
         where rooms.Apartment_id == i_apartmentId
         select rooms).ToList();
    return apartmentRooms;
}
```

Comment: Disable deferred loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try change the property of linqtosql.dbml , change the field of serilize from None to the second one.  Works for me.